# Duplicated Data from loop

Tags: javascript, loops, google-sheets

When I run the below script it duplicates some data, and I can't figure out why.  I am trying to copy rows from one sheet to another if Column K = "X".  If it does, I add a status of "New Hire" and today's date in Columns M and Q respectively.

When the script runs through its first loop, it works fine.  On subsequent loops, it also captures the data from previous loops.  I am unable to share the sheet in question for privacy reasons.  Here is the script I have that almost works...

```js
function copier() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('NewHires'); 
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('K:K');
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('Roster'); 
  var data = [];

  for each(i = 0; i < testvalue.length; i++) {
    if ( testvalue[i] == 'X') {
      data.push.apply(data, sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, 6).getValues());
    
      var clear = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, 6);
      var reset = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 9);

      csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
      reset.setValue(false);
      clear.clearContent();
 
      csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow(),13, 1, 1).setValue("New Hire");
      csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow(),17, 1, 1).setValue(new Date).setNumberFormat("mm/dd"); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Every step of the loop adds to data. Either replace it within the loop, or stop writing within the loop, and write once at the end.

Comment: @tehhowch...that is exactly what I need to know how to do.  I am still fairly new when it comes to scripting.

Comment: I suggest completing introductory JavaScript tutorials, especially in regards to loops. Just because you don't know how to program right now doesn't mean asking a question here absolves you of the requirement to learn the language you are working with. It should be very easy to identify which of the lines in your program write data to the spreadsheet. It should be similarly easy to identify which lines modify `data`. Then you simply must decide to write once, at the end, or write each time, within the loop, and the necessary adjustment to `data` will follow (extend vs replace, respectively).